# What is this "phantom" group?

Tags: linux, permissions, network-attached-storage

My LXC container mounts a NAS on `/share`.

```
$ ls -lha /
...
drwxrws---    8 nobody       4000  153 Mar 21 16:22 share
...
```

Since I cannot login as `nobody` user, I tried to make myself a member of the `4000` group. But that does not work since `4000` is not a group (?):

```
$ usermod -a -G 4000 root
usermod: group '4000' does not exist
```

What is this group `4000`? How can I work around accessing my NAS?

Comment: the file or folder seems to be created or copied from a other destination which handled the gid 4k. you can also `grep 4000 /etc/group* ` if it exists locally

Comment: @djdomi It is mounted from a NAS. It might be that GUID 4000 exists there, but I have no access to the NAS server. It definitely does not exist locally as long as `usermod` does not know about it.

Comment: you can create a group with the gidd if needed to